# When is the matrix invertable

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the value of $k$ for which the matrix is invertable.

$$ \left( \begin{matrix} 2&0&4&6 \\ k&4&3&2 \\ 3&0&1&4 \\ 2&3&0&3 \end{matrix} \right)$$

I just put it on reduced row form and got:

$$ \left( \begin{matrix} 1&0& 1/3 & 1/4 \\ 0&1& \frac{-(k-9)}{12} & \frac{-(2k-3)}{6} \\ 0&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{matrix} \right) $$

So it seems that the answer should be: For all values except $k=9$ but the answer states $k \neq \frac{7}{3}$.

What's wrong?

EDIT: It seems that the fraction is not even in the diagonal so it should be invertable for all k??

Comment: I've put a question about this before and I was told that reducing it to row echelon form and having the diagonal not equal zero would give me the answer?

Comment: @Amzoti : I do not think that is a good idea.. I guess what he has done is better than finding determinant... finding determinant of $4\times 4$ matrix is difficult right? :O

Comment: The rref is done by my texas. Is the rref wrong?

Comment: Can I ask why for $k=9$, the matrix is not invertible? On the other hand, to see what went wrong it is better to reconsider your reduction procedure.

Answer (score 2):

An $n \times n$ matrix is invertible $\iff$ its rows are linearly independent $\iff$ it has no zero rows when it is row reduced.  My advice to you is to check  your row-reduction.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $c_1,...,c_4$ are columns of the matrix. It is not difficult to see that:
$$
c_4-c_3-\frac{1}{3}c_2=\left(
\begin{matrix}
2\\
\frac{-7}{3}\\
3\\
2\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
So if $k=\frac{-7}{3}$ then $c_1=c_4-c_3-\frac{1}{3}c_2$ which means that the columns are not linearly independent. So the answer I get is $k\neq \frac{-7}{3}$.

---